# How to add a matrix of sprites to the screen in python

Tags: python, matrix, pygame

I was wondering how to draw a matrix with sprites and specific rows and columns to the screen. Here is my code so far:

```
rows = 3
cols = 6
choices = [Enemy(), Enemy2()]

def create_enemies():
matrix = [[np.random.choice(choices) for i in range(cols)] for j in range(rows)]
create_enemies()
```

except I dont know how to draw this matrix with the sprites to the screen. Any help?
Here are my enemy classes also:

```
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    speed = 2
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([40, 40])
        self.image = pygame.image.load("images/e1.png").convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(40,40))
        self.rect.x = 0
        self.rect.y = 0
    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += 1

class Enemy2(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    speed = 2
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([40, 40])
        self.image = pygame.image.load("images/e2.png").convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(40,40))
        self.rect.x = 0
        self.rect.y = 0
    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [`pygame.sprite.Group`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) instance and add the matrix to it:

```
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(matrix)
```

To update and draw all contained sprites, just call `all_sprites.update()` (calls the `update` method of the sprites) and `all_sprites.draw(screen)` in your main loop.

---

Note that your matrix contains only references to the two enemy instances in your `choices` list. If you want unique sprite instances change your code like so:

```
choices = [Enemy, Enemy2]  # Contains references to the classes now.
# Create new instances in the list comprehension.
matrix = [[random.choice(choices)() for i in range(cols)] for j in range(rows)]
```

There seems to be no reason to use numpy.

Comment: [Here's a sprite/sprite group tutorial.](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_sprites&lang=de#section_13)